# C -> COBOL interlanguage communication on mainframe

Tags: c, cobol, mainframe

A vendor package written in C on the mainframe offers the option to override a portion of it's functionality via a user exit.  The provided C function prototype is:

```
extern int SomeExit (void * Parameters,
                     void * Record1,
                     void * Record2,
                     char ComparisonType,
                     char * RankString,
                     void * NotUsed1,
                     int * NotUsed2)
```

As we are primarily a COBOL shop I defined an Enterprise COBOL 4.2 program (as a DLL) to implement the exit trying to follow the conventions given in the IBM ILC guide (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_1.13.0/com.ibm.zos.r13.ceea400/clcccb5.htm#clcccb5) and the examples in this old SHARE presentation: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27003846&aid=1 but the resulting program is abending as it calls the exit and prior to my `DISPLAY` message.  My assumption is that I have not declared the receiving data structures correctly.  Below is a snippet of my current test code (ignore my naming conventions - this is a prototype to prove out the interface and will be rewritten to our in-house standards once I have the basic call working).

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.   
PROGRAM-ID.    "SomeExit". 
...
LINKAGE SECTION.                                               
01  WS-PARAMETERS-POINTER       USAGE IS POINTER SYNCHRONIZED. 
01  SORT-PASS-RECORD1-POINTER   USAGE IS POINTER SYNCHRONIZED. 
01  SORT-PASS-RECORD2-POINTER   USAGE IS POINTER SYNCHRONIZED. 
01  WS-COMPARISION-TYPE         PIC X.
01  WS-RANK-STRING-POINTER      USAGE IS POINTER SYNCHRONIZED. 
01  WS-NOT-USED1-POINTER        USAGE IS POINTER SYNCHRONIZED. 
01  WS-NOT-USED2-POINTER        USAGE IS POINTER SYNCHRONIZED. 
01  WS-RETURN                   PIC S9(9) USAGE IS BINARY.
...
PROCEDURE DIVISION USING BY VALUE WS-PARAMETERS-POINTER     
                     SORT-PASS-RECORD1-POINTER          
                     SORT-PASS-RECORD2-POINTER          
                     WS-COMPARISION-TYPE                
                     WS-RANK-STRING-POINTER             
                     WS-NOT-USED1-POINTER               
                     WS-NOT-USED2-POINTER               
               RETURNING WS-RETURN.                     

DISPLAY 'IN EXIT'.
... 
MOVE 0 TO WS-RETURN.
GOBACK.
```

The abend is:

```
CEE3250C The system or user abend U 016 R=00000000 was issued.                                                     
     From entry point main at compile unit offset +00000192 at entry offset +00000192 at address 28500ECA.
```

The vendor code calls the DLL dynamically.  When I delete the DLL I get a message that the exit cannot be found and so it seems like the C code is attempting to call it.

I have tried variations on the `PROCEDURE DIVISION USING` including dropping the `BY VALUE`, using `BY REFERENCE` (though I understand that is the default) and replacing the `POINTERs` with the actual structure definitions.  Have I misunderstood the manual on how to structure the parameters passed to the COBOL routine?

Edit: I do have a support ticket open with the vendor but they have not responded with anything useful yet.

Thanks, David

Comment: What abend? What displacement in what program? Why `BY VALUE` for everything, I would have thought for comparison-type only, the others BY REFERENCE? Are you aware of what that does? Forget `SYNCHRONIZED`. Why WS- prefix for your LINKAGE SECTION items? Strictly you should always set WS-RETURN to something before GOBACK. Which version of Enterprise COBOL? Is the the call from the C coming from a DLL? Have you asked the vendor (you license includes support).

Comment: 23 views in an hour, and two upvotes. That's a Wow! for a COBOL question. Probably means more C than COBOL people reading, and more non-Mainframe than Mainframe :-)

Comment: What is your `PROGRAM-ID`? Is the exit meant to be statically linked or is the vendor-routine `fetch`ing your cobol-dll?

Comment: I've updated the original question to answer some of the clarifications  posed by Bill & Piet.

Comment: Thanks. `From entry point main` indicates that the abend has come from a C (or C++) program, as Enterprise COBOL does not have "main" - if it was an abend in your program, it would say SomeExit at that point. It is a User Abend, with a code of 16. User Abends are specific to an application. The product you are running has generated the Abend. It means that it has identified something as incorrect, and the incorrectness was terminal. Check the any spool files (from number three onwards) as there may (or may not) be additional messages.

Comment: Since without your module present at all you get a failure (although which Abend code for that? S806?) @piet.t's point about whether the exit is supposed to be statically linked or not is worth confirming in the documentation for the exit. For the POINTER items, use BY REFERENCE. For the other, you can use BY VALUE. I think you are OK leaving the RETURNING item as it is. I can't imagine a way that any changes there would affect the abend. Do you know if the vendor code is 64-bit? If yes, forget using a COBOL program for it.#

Comment: You have to ask the vendor what a U16 is in that code. You may be able to get a module name by matching up the address, or if not it depends what you can "see" in the dump. You are close to the end of what you can do with this.

Comment: I've made progress enough that the exit is being called.  I'll post the solution  later once I've verified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I was able to determine a solution based on better understanding of the calling structure per Bills suggestion.  Given this C prototype:

```
extern int SomeExit (void * Parameters,
                     void * Record1,
                     void * Record2,
                     char ComparisonType,
                     char * RankString,
                     void * NotUsed1,
                     int * NotUsed2)
```

The solution:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.     
PROGRAM-ID.    "SomeExit".   
...
LINKAGE SECTION.      
01  WS-PARAMETERS        PIC X(10).    
01  SORT-PASS-RECORD1    PIC X(50).    
01  SORT-PASS-RECORD2    PIC X(50).    
01  WS-COMPARISON-TYPE   PIC X.
01  WS-RANK-STRING       PIC X(6).                  
01  WS-NOT-USED1         PIC X.                     
01  WS-NOT-USED2         PIC X.                     
01  WS-RETURN            PIC S9(9) USAGE IS BINARY.
... 
PROCEDURE DIVISION USING                     
        BY REFERENCE WS-PARAMETERS       
        BY REFERENCE SORT-PASS-RECORD1   
        BY REFERENCE SORT-PASS-RECORD2   
        BY VALUE     WS-COMPARISON-TYPE  
        BY REFERENCE WS-RANK-STRING      
        BY REFERENCE WS-NOT-USED1        
        BY REFERENCE WS-NOT-USED2        
           RETURNING WS-RETURN.          
    DISPLAY 'IN EXIT'.
    ... 
    MOVE 0 TO WS-RETURN.
    GOBACK.
```

With the above the user exit was successfully called and returned a value to the vendor logic.  I used the following parameters for compilation `RENT, TRUNC(BIN), DLL,EXPORTALL` and for linking `DYNAM(DLL),RENT`.  Not needed for my application but if the calling program is expecting a mixed case routine name in the called program as used in the above example solution then `PGMNAME(LONGMIXED)` would have been needed also.

Thanks to all the commenters for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. I didn't notice the ... before. If you had code there using the parameters, you would have clobbered something somewhere. Did you just not see the output from the DISPLAY (no SYSOUT DD?)? Or did the compile/linkedit/binder options fix the abend? Anyway, good work.

Comment: @BillWoodger yes the ... referenced logic that read the parameters (but didn't update them), not relevant to the issue I was having though. Until I made the change it wasn't getting to the display statement.